# Loss of geometry in shapefile after saving edits

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometry

I'm using QGIS 2.18.17

When I'm editing (e.g. removing objects) from a shapefile in QGIS and click to save the edits, all geometries are lost. All non-deleted objects are still present, but they do no longer contain a geometry (no objects visible in the layer and, when copying the objects from the attribute table in an Excel-document, the column "wkt_geom" is filled with NULL for all objects).

At first, I thought the problem only occurred with a point layer (shapefile), but today it also occurred with a polygon layer (shapefile).

The same thing occurred when I wanted to save a selection from a point layer as a new shapefile. The shapefile is created and the dbf-table is complete, but no geometries are present.

As I cannot imagine it concerns a bug in the used version of QGIS (as it is such a basic functionality), I assume the problem arises when saving the file with extension .shp (which stores the geometry) of the shapefile.

I'm working at a local government and the environment which I'm working on is a thin client (access through a Citrix viewer to a remote server) where a desktop environment is created which is identical for all users within the local government. All data is also stored on the same remote servers.

Anyone who had a similar problem in the past and found a way to solve it?

Edit: further investigation indicated that the cause eventually could be found in the way QGIS handles the network folders (on a Windows 2012 R2 Server), as the problem does not occur when writing on the local disk. Could it be something with some difference between relative and absolute paths? I already tried to switch this setting (without closing QGIS) but without result.

Comment: Did you try to split your geometries into single objects? Somehow sounds like you have multipoints/polygons.

Comment: No, it always consisted in individual points, no multipoints or polygons

Comment: Have you tried running a Check Validity (Processing tools) and/or Check Geometries (Vector menu) on your problem layers?

Comment: Yes using the Check Geometry tool in QGIS, no problems were present

Answer (score 1):

I had similar geometry issues due projection. Are your data projected? If not, project it to any reference system that you prefer and work with a defined projection.

Comment: All data are projected with EPSG 31370

Comment: If your edits are only about deleting objects, maybe you can select the objects that you want from the original data and export them to a new shapefile. Or maybe the problem is where you are storing the data. Try to use a file geodatabase or the default geodatabase. Sometimes I just solved weird problems changing it.

Comment: The export to a new shapefile results in the same problem.

I know I could change e.g. to a Spatialite-layer, but this should anyhow be possible with shapefiles too. Furthermore, I need to have the data in shapefile-format later on for other uses.